# How to Map Native Query result to java Class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, native

I am working on java nativequery in jpa.I have get result in class  Practice  but how i map the distance variable to my Practice  class .Please help me.

```
List<Practice> resultData=(List<Practice>)em.createNativeQuery("SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?1) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?2) ) + sin( radians(?1) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM tb_practice HAVING distance < 200 ORDER BY distance;",Practice.class)
        .setParameter(1, latitude)
        .setParameter(2, longitude)
        .getResultList();
```

This is Result of my query: Please help how to map distance variable to my class practice.

[image]

---

```
@Entity(name = "tb_practice")
public class Practice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String address;

    private String city;

    private String distance;
}
```

This is Pratice table.

Comment: Is the mapping given in mapping file properly done ?

Comment: in which mapping file? i have just created variable in modal and it gatter setter in modal and nothing done else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need both a group by as a derived table expression.

You need to list all tb_practice table columns instead of column1...columnN, so this is your query:

```
List<Practice> resultData= (List<Practice>)
    em.createNativeQuery("
    SELECT NEW Practice(    
        p.id, 
        p.address,
        p.city) 
    FROM 
    (   
        SELECT 
            p.id, 
            p.address,
            p.city,
            ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?1) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?2) ) + sin( radians(?1) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM 
            tb_practice 
        GROUP BY
            p.id, 
            p.address,
            p.city
        HAVING distance < 200 
        ORDER BY distance
    ) practice_by_distance  
    ",Practice.class)
    .setParameter(1, latitude)
    .setParameter(2, longitude)
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: I can't understand what you want to say?Can you give a little example?

Comment: Post the tb_practice table and I'll modify the example to include all your table columns.

Comment: I have posted our Practice table.Please check